# Convert Subselect to Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this Subselect query that I'd like to be able to convert to an Eloquent query. Could anyone help please?

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM `visits` WHERE `exit` = 0 ORDER BY `updated_at` DESC ) visits GROUP BY `visits`.`session_id`';
```

Thanks

Comment: Post the DB schema, what is the value of $table? What models to you have?

Comment: Updated the question. I got the answer though myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the query working with a join:

```
Visit::select('visits.*')->
join(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM `visits` WHERE `exit` = 0 ORDER BY `updated_at` DESC, `id` DESC) v2'), 'visits.id', '=', 'v2.id')->
groupBy('visits.session_id')->get();
```

Comment: You really need a raw query in this case? You should avoid them. The more Eloquent you can use, the safer will be your application.